# Ideals in Commutative Banach Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Suppose that $A$ is a natural Banach function algebra on $K$, a compact Hausdorff space.  So $A$ is realised as an algebra of continuous functions on $K$, is a Banach algebra for some norm (necessarily dominating the supremum norm) and each character on $A$ is given by evaluation at a point of $K$.

If $F\subseteq K$ is closed, then $$ I(F)=\{f\in A : f(k)=0 \ (k\in F) \}$$ is a closed ideal in $A$.  If e.g. $A=C(K)$ then every closed ideal is of this form.

> What's a simple example of an $A$ where not every closed ideal is of this form?

If I look in Bonsall+Duncan, I find that the Disc Algebra is an example.  But quite a bit of theory is needed to show this.  I'd like an easy example which I can explain to students.  For bonus marks:

> Can we find an $A$ which is conjugate closed?

Comment: how can we prove that I(F) is closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$C^1([0,1])$  - take the ideal of functions which vanish at $p$ and whose derivatives vanish at $p$.

Comment: D'oh!  That was easy... Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I just happen to have got stuck on / noticed this some years ago while messing around with hulls and kernels